# Visio VBA Access to the macros sources

Tags: vba, visio

I need to get Macros text from the Visio document using VBA. Is there any collection, property etc to access to the macros of the Visio document?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the code in the VBA project for a document, assuming it's unlocked for viewing and the Visio installation security settings allows programmatic access to the VBA project.

If you have a document variable called Doc, it would be Doc.VBProject

If you enable the Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility library in the references, you can dim a variable as VBProject and get intellisense to help you figure out how to get what you need.